# Inconsistent Switch display

Tags: android, user-interface

Does anyone know why the Switch widget behaves differently in two different apps?

Both of them are using build tool 26.0.1 and 26.1.0 sdk.

```
<Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

```
<Switch android:id                      ="@+id/imgbtn_settings_noti_daily"
        android:layout_width            ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height           ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edttxt_settings_about_me"/>
```

[image]

Comment: most likely has something to do with the theme of the activity.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be differences in `styles.xml` file related to `switch`

so I suggest you to check both apps `styles.xml` file (or `theme` applied)

and you might get it.

Comment: both apps both this theme: @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: did you check both `styles.xml` files too?